# How to connect a google cloud function to cassandra database in kubernetes cluster

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, google-cloud-functions

I deployed a cassandra cluster in google cloud platform with kubernetes (with terraform).

The cassandra cluster is working well, I'm running some commands with `kubectl exec -it cassandra-0 bash` and the data is propagating to all other nodes, all is working well.

When I run `host cassandra` I see this:

```
cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local has address 10.32.1.4
cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local has address 10.32.1.5
cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local has address 10.32.3.12
```

Until here, all is right.

But now I have a question that I don't know how to solve.
I have an Google Cloud Function that I want to connect to this database and insert some data.

What is the best way to do this? I guess that I shouldn't expose the database to the internet. But when I try to connect cloud function to `cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local` I can't see the server.

I use `cluster_ip = "None"` on the cassandra service

UPDATED: Added the following information:

My Google Cloud Function is this:

```
exports.helloGET = function helloGET (req, res) {
    const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
    const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local'], localDataCenter: 'DC1', keyspace: 'my_bd_name' });

    const query = 'SELECT * FROM User';
    client.execute(query)
        .then(result => console.log('Users: ', dump(result.rows)));

    res.send('Cassandra loaded... :' + dump(result.rows));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A full [SRV record](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#srv-records) is expected.

> ### SRV records
>
> SRV Records are created for named ports that are part of normal or Headless Services. For each named port, the SRV record would have the form `_my-port-name._my-port-protocol.my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`. For a regular service, this resolves to the port number and the domain name: `my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`. For a headless service, this resolves to multiple answers, one for each pod that is backing the service, and contains the port number and the domain name of the pod of the form `auto-generated-name.my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`.

In your case you created a headless service (without a cluster IP as you used `cluster_ip = "None"`) and need to find the `auto-generated-name` of `auto-generated-name.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local`.

Comment: Thanks, How can I find this autogenerated name?

Comment: And another question, can the Google Cloud Functions see the cassandra server without expose cassandra ports to the world in internet?

Comment: Not sure about Functions, it doesn't seem to be able to use internal IPs for normal compute instances. You might need to expose Cassandra to the internet. 

Maybe [this page](https://supergiant.io/blog/kubernetes-dns-for-services-and-pods/) for debugging Kubernetes DNS can help.